# 3D Sumif on all sheets that contain "CL -" in sheet name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a document that can have sheets added and taken away on a weekly basis but I need the overview sheet to do a calculation (sumif) on all relevant sheets.

I have created a ***`3D sumif`*** but cant get it to reference sheets like i want to... all relevant sheets include the text `Cl - xxxx` (This means client tab, and then client name which can be anything) I currently have 20+ Client Tabs.

This is my formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$B$5:$B$25&"'!$B$60:$B$999"),$A4,INDIRECT("'"&$B$5:$B$25&"'!D$60:D$999")))
```

`$B$5:$B$25` is currently a list of the tabs but I just want it to be based on if a tab name contains the `"Cl -"` Due the the adding and removing of sheets I can't use a sheet name list moving forwards as the people that use this document do not keep it updated and then are frustrated when it doesn't work!

Any ideas? Do I need some VBA Code? Am I attacking it in a wrong way?

Comment: My advice: use VBA; From what I know, its rather easy to manipulate sheets by name with VBA. However manipulating formulas is a little tricky, but you could come up on excellent material here.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about writing code in VBA, I wouldn't even know if a piece of code was what I was looking for if I saw it.

Comment: You say "all relevant sheets include the text Cl- xxxx" but then "based on if a tab name contains the "Cl -"". The first does not contain a space between "CI" and "-", the second does. Which is it?

Comment: @XOR LX - Sorry, they all have "CL -" and then another space and the client name. Edited now.

Comment: So a solution that includes only tabs which contain "CL - " will suffice?

Comment: Yes, i am basically trying to sumif accross any tabs that include "CL -" in the tab name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to save your file as `macro-enabled`, even if this set-up does not require explicit entering of any `VBA`.

First go to `Name Manager` and make the following two definitions:

*Name*: `FullSheetNames`

*Refers to*: `=GET.WORKBOOK(1)&T(NOW())`

*Name*: `SheetNames`

*Refers to*: `=MID(FullSheetNames,FIND("]",FullSheetNames)+1,255)`

The required **array formula**** is then:

`=SUM(IFERROR(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CL -",SheetNames)),SheetNames)&"'!$B$60:$B$999"),$A4,INDIRECT("'"&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CL -",SheetNames)),SheetNames)&"'!D$60:D$999")),0))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: This is truly amazing, thank you so much!!! i wish i had the knowledge to work out how and why this works, a lot of research for me now! thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! I can add an explanation if you like.

Comment: That would really help if thats not too much trouble!

Comment: and now my boss has asked me to create a formula that will return a list of the sheet names where a criteria has been met (that include an employees name in column A)... she loves setting me these "out of my knowledge base" tasks!

Comment: Re this new query, can you clarify?

Comment: Sure, i just hope it makes sense... so the formula you have provided above looks at all of the client sheets and adds together the hours our employees have been allocated against each one ($A4 is the employee name that is in cells B60:B999) so we can see how many hours each person has been allocated in cells D60:D999. Now she wants a "helper" sheet where she can put an employees name in A1 and then in A3 downwards it will list the Client tabs that include that employee's name in B60:B999. She also wants B3 downwards to list the hours that are on the Client tabs in D60:D999.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but what about your new request re sheet names?

Comment: Also, i forgot to mention that in the client sheets A60:A999 (before the name of employee) we enter the type of work they will be doing for this client, she wants this to be pulled through to the "helper" sheet. Is there a way i could upload my workbook for you to actually see?

Comment: I think that would make things a lot easier! You'd need to use some sharesite and upload to that and send me the link. Or send to me personally at xorlx99@gmail.com.

Comment: Emailed to you directly